# Convert time (text) to Excel formatted Time

Tags: excel, time, format

I have a list of durations in minutes used to log calls and I want to use Excel to format them and do some calculations. However, these are just exported as table and when I attempt to bring them into Excel, the cells won't format correctly.

An example below:

01:00 is entered as the number of minutes and seconds

However, when I try to use Excels cell format it turns it into 
01:00:00 as in hours, minutes, seconds (hh:mm:ss).

Now I want to convert it to this as I also have the cost per minute which I then need to multiply by this time.
To clarify further as to why it needs to be in this format, is because i want to use the follow query to get the total cost per minute.

```
=(HOUR(H4)*60*I4)+(MINUTE(H4)*I4)+(SECOND(H4)/60*I4)
```

Can anyone help with how to get Excel to recognise this in mm:ss format.

Comment: just getting this straight, this basically boils down to you want to display the time in only minutes and seconds, but other than that everything else works?  That formula you have at the end should work just fine assuming that I4 is your price per minute and H4 is your time saved in an excel date/time format.

Comment: the cell containing your Time, lets assume H4, when you use the formula =ISNUMBER(H4) what do you get?

Comment: Your title is misleading as there is no text time to convert since your time is already a number.

Comment: Try dividing the time by **60** this will convert the erroneous *hh:mm* into *mm:ss*

Comment: Ok, that was ridiculously easy and works perfectly. *Embarrassed*
If you want to put it as an answer will mark as correct :)

Comment: &(*^%#&(*# I missed the line that 01:00 was minutes and second but being read as hours and minutes.... GRRR

Comment: do you have any durations over 60 minutes?  if so what is happening with them? actually source duration of over 24 minutes, what is happening with them?

Comment: Anything over 60 minutes it is converting to an hour, which is great. and the something like 28:00 is converting to 00:28:00 as it want it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this workaround.  Format A column to be "text" type.  Paste your data into column A.  Format B column to be "custom" type, choose "mm:ss".  Copy below formula down column B.

A1:  `01:00`

B2: `=0+("00:"&A1)`

B column will display and function as you desire.